# How to re-calculate the stop and resume animation calculation correctly in my project

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I have a problem with **pausing** the **story**.

**below are some points:**

1. without clicking for next story `pause` works **fine**
2. when `next story` is `clicked`  the story will jump to the next `story` with is code `window.location.href = '#'+storyId;`
3. after `next story clicked` **the problem with pause occurs**
4. **pause can be triggred** with `space bar` or `right click (contextmenu)`

**for pause these functions are called in this fashion:**

1. `toggleAnimation()`
2. `pauseAnimation();` in this function this code `editor.postMessage( {'request':command.pause}, getDomain() );`  triggers `listener();`
3. `listener()` with command `command.pause` this comes into this switch block

   `case command.pause :
            requestAnimationFrame(localPauseAnimation);
            play=false;
            syncPrompters();
            break;`
4. `localPauseAnimation();`

**below code is responsible for animation (inside `animation()`):**

```
 styleSheet.insertRule('\
            .prompt.move {\
                transform: translateY('+destination+'px) scale('+(flipH?-1:1)+','+(flipV?-1:1)+') !important;\
                transition: transform '+time+'ms '+curve+';\
        }', 0);
```

**I'm working with this open source project**  https://imaginarysense.github.io/Teleprompter-Core/  **it is very difficult for me to crack this code**

**steps to reproduce:**

1. extract downloaded folder(https://www.dropbox.com/s/e7c2d4fynwl1d6a/Teleprompter-Core-master.tar.gz?dl=0) find `index.html` run into browser
2. click on `Prompt It` on the top right corner
3. (wait for 10sec) stories will come slides into window, press `space bar` it will stop correctly
4. when `next stores` (red color) button is pressed then press `space bar` for **pause** stories will jump now on the subsequent press of `space bar`
5. whole code for animation can be found in `js/teleprompter.js`

**whole code for animation can be found in `js/teleprompter.js`**

**Question:** pause and play should work as normal, without any jump

project link: https://www.dropbox.com/s/e7c2d4fynwl1d6a/Teleprompter-Core-master.tar.gz?dl=0

Answer (score 2):

Play and pause animation depends on cursor position. Current cursor potion value is calculated by top position of div with class name "prompt move". I think problem with top position value of prompt div. The top value of prompt div change when you call **window.location.href = '#'+storyId;**. So current cursor position will be changed.
Following function is responsible to calculate cursor position.

```
function getCurrPos(obj) {
    // There's more than a way to calculate the current position.
    // This is the original method, slower and more reliable. Used only for Intergalactic Style, where the other method fails.
    if (promptStyleOption===4) {
        if (!obj)
            obj=prompt;
        var computedStyle = window.getComputedStyle(obj, null),
            theMatrix = computedStyle.getPropertyValue("transform"),
        // Reading data from matrix.
            mat = theMatrix.match(/^matrix3d\((.+)\)$/);
        if (mat) return parseFloat(mat[1].split(', ')[13]);
            mat = theMatrix.match(/^matrix\((.+)\)$/);
        return mat ? parseFloat(mat[1].split(', ')[5]) : 0;
    }
    // This method is faster, and it's prefered because it generates less lag. Unfortunatelly it fails to calculate in 3D space.
    else
        return prompt.getBoundingClientRect().top;
}
```

The issue will be solved if we change getCurrPos function to following way.

```
function getCurrPos(obj) {
        // There's more than a way to calculate the current position.
        // This is the original method, slower and more reliable. Used only for Intergalactic Style, where the other method fails.
            if (!obj)
                obj=prompt;
            var computedStyle = window.getComputedStyle(obj, null),
                theMatrix = computedStyle.getPropertyValue("transform"),
            // Reading data from matrix.
                mat = theMatrix.match(/^matrix3d\((.+)\)$/);
            if (mat) return parseFloat(mat[1].split(', ')[13]);
                mat = theMatrix.match(/^matrix\((.+)\)$/);
            return mat ? parseFloat(mat[1].split(', ')[5]) : 0;
    }
```

> N:B This issue will not occur by default when we prompt it by setting
>   Prompter style to whiteboard.

Comment: you have understood my **problem correctly**, it solved some what my problem, even though it will jump when i **pause** the story. thanks your **Great Solution**.  please help me furthur.

Comment: @skBangalore I have tested in my own system, It is not jump any more when I pause the story.You can check this by default (without changing any code) setting Prompter style to whiteboard.

Comment: Great it works for me too on **White board** what about other prompter styles, can you please check? Please help me

Comment: It will also work for other prompter styles if you update the code of  getCurrPos function according to my answer of this question

Comment: @EaB Thanks for your award. I have just debug source code using Chrome developer tool and I found the issue.